# Cube rotation with css

Tags: html, css

I am having a bit of an issue with rotation of a cube. I want to make it cross-browser so I am transforming every side of the cube. When I am rotating from left to right the sides align perfectly on all browsers Chrome, Firefox and IE, BUT when the cube is rotated from top to bottom, the sides align only on Chrome (If I make the animation slower on Chrome the sides are broken the same way as the other browsers, so I think working properly is a bug :D). I have provided an example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/0n9bnxe5/

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-card-content">
  <div class="flip-card-side-a" style="background:red">
    FRONT 
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card-side-b" style="background:green">
    BACK
  </div>
  <div class="flip-card-side-c" style="background:aqua">
    LEFT
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button">Flip-top</button>
<button id="button2">Filp-right</button>
```

CSS:

```
.flip-card-content {
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective:1000px;
}

.flip-card-side-a,
.flip-card-side-b,
.flip-card-side-c{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform-origin:50% 50% 0px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.flip-card-side-a {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
  z-index: 1;
}
.flip-card-side-b {
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.flip-card-side-c {
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.flip .flip-card-side-a {

  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.flip .flip-card-side-b {
  display:block;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
  z-index: 1;
}
.flip-right .flip-card-side-a {
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.flip-

right .flip-card-side-b {
  display:none;
}
.flip-right .flip-card-side-c {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
  z-index:1;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#button").on('click', function(){
  $(".flip-card-content").removeClass("flip-right");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".flip-card-content").toggleClass("flip");
   },500);
});

$("#button2").on('click', function(){
  $(".flip-card-content").removeClass("flip");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".flip-card-content").toggleClass("flip-right");
  },500);

});
```

Any advice is welcomed!

Comment: Why your cube has only 3 sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transition in 3d space are tricky, and different browsers can handle them differently.

Here you have your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0n9bnxe5/2/) corrected.

Your best bet is to leave nothing to the browser imagination

so, instead of changing

```
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
```

to

```
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
```

make the change happen from

```
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(100px);
```

to

```
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0deg)  translateZ(100px);
```

Notice that I didn't change the transform from a mathematical point of view; but now every property matches a similar one.

**Note** just in case you want to know, in the first case IE is making the followng transition: change the angle of rotation from 0 to -90deg. At the same time, change the axis of rotation from Y to X. So, at the middle of the transition, the rotation is wrong (from your point of view), but in a mathematic sense, both ways of understanding the transition make sense.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work properly on the Samsung Galaxy S3, Cynogenmod 11 with Google Chrome. Because I can see 3 seperate plains when turning from left to top.

Comment: @martijnn2008 the transition from *left* to *top* is not intended to work, it breaks in all the browsers. but I don't think that the OP was asking about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your `translateZ` doesn't quite work in the way you expect.  Have look at how I've positioned the faces on the cube here and compare it to your own.  Ultimately, I find the easiest way to rotate items such as cubes etc. is to position all the elements and then just rotate the container.

Also for nice scaling of fonts, images etc. its preferable to leave the front face at its natural size rather than scale up (i.e. move everything backward in 3d space):

```
.box {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% -100px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1s;
    width: 100%;
}

.box--rotate-top {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.box--rotate-left {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
}

.box__face {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.box__face--front {
    background: #f90;
}

.box__face--top {
    background: #369;
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
    transform-origin: 0 100% 0;
}

.box__face--left {
    background: #867;
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
    transform-origin: 100% 0 0;
}
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8w6fmuj/).

Comment: Yes, I too think that this is the easiest way, rotating the container, but IE doesn't have preserve-3d keyword yet, and I need it to work in IE too.

Comment: Understood, well you can still apply the same transition CSS from the container to each individual child element (I.e. all the transitioned rotation positions). The main issues was the way you had applied your `translateZ`.